# What are the Best Practices for insulation, vapour barriers et al on a vintage RV with a single sheet galvanized metal roof. From the inside

Tags: vapor-barrier, metal-roof, trailer, styrofoam

Likely due to bearing heavy snow loads ( previous owner(s) ) The single sheet galvanized roof developed a few dips where water collects. When the water is deep enough it infiltrates around the edges and flows to the lowest point of the ceiling panel naturally. We can resolve this issue. But while we are redoing the ceiling inside we might as well increase the insulation as much as we can.

- We will be doing all work from the inside.
- We have a number of 2 inch thick blue board styrofoam insulation we
  want to use.
- If we have to lower the ceiling somewhat it is not the end of the
  world.
- We do not want to pierce the metal roof in any way
- The ceiling is 8'9" wide by 15' long
- There is no sheathing under the metal.
  It has lasted that way more than 40 years.

We would appreciate tips and info re vapour barrier, air space, fastening methods, anything like that!